# HTML5 capturing absolute position following rotation and translation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I'm trying to manipulate a simple rectangle on a HTML5 canvas.  The Javascript that does this is here:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

var halfWidth = (iconWidth / 2);
var halfHeight = (iconHeight / 2);

var centreX = x + halfWidth;
var centreY = y + halfHeight;

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.translate(centreX, centreY);
ctx.rotate(rotationDegree * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, iconWidth, iconHeight);

ctx.translate(-centreX, -centreY);
```

As I increase `y`, I can see the rectangle travelling along the screen and, if I rotate the rectangle, it rotates and moves along the new trajectory; however, in order to stop the rectangle leaving the screen, I had a basic boundary check, which was just not working (the rectangle was travelling off the screen, and being "bounced" where it had not reached the edge.

As an experiment, I then tried the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

var halfWidth = (iconWidth / 2);
var halfHeight = (iconHeight / 2);

var centreX = x + halfWidth;
var centreY = y + halfHeight;

ctx.save();

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.translate(centreX, centreY);
ctx.rotate(rotationDegree * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, iconWidth, iconHeight);

//        ctx.translate(-centreX, -centreY);
ctx.restore();
```

This works, but the rotation no longer guides the rectangle.  My conclusion is that the rotate function rotates the canvas, but then leaves it in the new, rotated form (like rotating a piece of paper underneath a pen).  So, the bug I had was that the rotation was not being reset; however, apart from the boundary check, this "bugged" behaviour was what I was actually aiming for.

Is there a way to get from a canvas 2d context the absolute position, taking into account the rotation so that, even if I leave the canvas in its "rotated" state, I can perform a boundary check?

[Here is a fiddle of the site.](https://jsfiddle.net/sd9zekg2/)

Answer (score 2):

To transform a point from local space (the transformed space) to screen space create a matrix that is a shadow (copy) of the context transform then multiply the point with that matrix

```
function getTransformToScreen(x,y,rotation,posX,posY){
    var xAx = Math.cos(rotation);  // x axis x
    var xAy = Math.sin(rotation);  // x axis y
    // the equivalent to 
    // ctx setTransform(xAx, xAy ,-xAy, xAx, posX, posY);
    // second two values (y Axis) is at 90 deg of x Axis if it is
    // not at 90 (skewed) then you need to calculate the skewed axis (y axis) direction
    return {
        x : x * xAx - y * xAy + posX,
        y : x * xAy + y * xAx + posY
    }
}
```

To use

```
// your code
ctx.translate(centreX, centreY);
ctx.rotate(rotationDegree * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, iconWidth, iconHeight);
// get the top left
var topLeft = getTransformToScreen(
    -halfWidth, -halfHeight,
    rotationDegree * Math.PI / 180,
    centreX, centreY
);
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've updated the question with a fiddle, as it's not functioning exactly as I would expect.